# JBoss EAP modules maven depencency

Tags: java, maven, jboss

Do you know if there are any maven artifacts (similar to org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all), where I can have all provided libraries of the JBoss EAP at once?

I use [this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673) page as a reference for JBoss EAP library versioning, but it's a bit cumbersome to add them one by one for every new project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something as a BOM (Bill Of Materials). There are several for JBoss. https://github.com/jboss-eap/jboss-bom

I found a tutorial on how to use it with some more details. http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/maven-and-jboss-how-to-use-boms It's a bit old but hopefully this is the direction you was looking for.

Comment: Hm, not what I hoped for I guess :P